# MySQL with Python Flask in Openshift: Internal Server Error

Tags: python, mysql, flask, openshift, flask-sqlalchemy

The first weird thing is that just fails when it's deployed in Openshift, in my localhost works perfectly.

The issue occurs when I try to login a user(query in mysql).

http://scheduler-sonrie.rhcloud.com/testdb  -> this test mysql connection and seems OK,

http://scheduler-sonrie.rhcloud.com/signin  -> fail reporting a message "Internal Server Error"

This is my code https://github.com/rchampa/scheduler-old

There are a few errors when I deploy:

```
remote:     /usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lmysqlclient
remote:     collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
remote:     error: command 'gcc' failed with exit status 1
remote:     Can't roll back MySQL-python; was not uninstalled
```

And this is the entire logs when I deploy app.

```
remote: Stopping Python 2.7 cartridge
remote: Syncing git content to other proxy gears
remote: Building git ref 'master', commit bf9510c
remote: Activating virtenv
remote: Checking for pip dependency listed in requirements.txt file..
remote: Requirement already satisfied (use --upgrade to upgrade): aniso8601==0.92 in /var/lib/openshift/549c86454382ecb3c400010c/app-root/runtime/dependencies/python/virtenv/lib/python2.7/site-packages (from -r /var/lib/openshift/549c86454382ecb3c400010c/app-root/runtime/repo/requirements.txt (line 1))
remote: Requirement already satisfied (use --upgrade to upgrade): Flask==0.10.1 in /var/lib/openshift/549c86454382ecb3c400010c/app-root/runtime/dependencies/python/virtenv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/Flask-0.10.1-py2.7.egg (from -r /var/lib/openshift/549c86454382ecb3c400010c/app-root/runtime/repo/requirements.txt (line 2))
remote: Requirement already satisfied (use --upgrade to upgrade): Flask-HTTPAuth==2.3.0 in /var/lib/openshift/549c86454382ecb3c400010c/app-root/runtime/dependencies/python/virtenv/lib/python2.7/site-packages (from -r /var/lib/openshift/549c86454382ecb3c400010c/app-root/runtime/repo/requirements.txt (line 3))
remote: Requirement already satisfied (use --upgrade to upgrade): Flask-RESTful==0.3.1 in /var/lib/openshift/549c86454382ecb3c400010c/app-root/runtime/dependencies/python/virtenv/lib/python2.7/site-packages (from -r /var/lib/openshift/549c86454382ecb3c400010c/app-root/runtime/repo/requirements.txt (line 4))
remote: Requirement already satisfied (use --upgrade to upgrade): Flask-SQLAlchemy==2.0 in /var/lib/openshift/549c86454382ecb3c400010c/app-root/runtime/dependencies/python/virtenv/lib/python2.7/site-packages (from -r /var/lib/openshift/549c86454382ecb3c400010c/app-root/runtime/repo/requirements.txt (line 5))
remote: Requirement already satisfied (use --upgrade to upgrade): Flask-WTF==0.10.3 in /var/lib/openshift/549c86454382ecb3c400010c/app-root/runtime/dependencies/python/virtenv/lib/python2.7/site-packages (from -r /var/lib/openshift/549c86454382ecb3c400010c/app-root/runtime/repo/requirements.txt (line 6))
remote: Requirement already satisfied (use --upgrade to upgrade): itsdangerous==0.24 in /var/lib/openshift/549c86454382ecb3c400010c/app-root/runtime/dependencies/python/virtenv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/itsdangerous-0.24-py2.7.egg (from -r /var/lib/openshift/549c86454382ecb3c400010c/app-root/runtime/repo/requirements.txt (line 7))
remote: Requirement already satisfied (use --upgrade to upgrade): Jinja2==2.7.3 in /var/lib/openshift/549c86454382ecb3c400010c/app-root/runtime/dependencies/python/virtenv/lib/python2.7/site-packages (from -r /var/lib/openshift/549c86454382ecb3c400010c/app-root/runtime/repo/requirements.txt (line 8))
remote: Requirement already satisfied (use --upgrade to upgrade): MarkupSafe==0.23 in /var/lib/openshift/549c86454382ecb3c400010c/app-root/runtime/dependencies/python/virtenv/lib/python2.7/site-packages (from -r /var/lib/openshift/549c86454382ecb3c400010c/app-root/runtime/repo/requirements.txt (line 9))
remote: Downloading/unpacking MySQL-python==1.2.5 (from -r /var/lib/openshift/549c86454382ecb3c400010c/app-root/runtime/repo/requirements.txt (line 10))
remote:   Running setup.py egg_info for package MySQL-python
remote:     
remote: Requirement already satisfied (use --upgrade to upgrade): pytz==2014.10 in /var/lib/openshift/549c86454382ecb3c400010c/app-root/runtime/dependencies/python/virtenv/lib/python2.7/site-packages (from -r /var/lib/openshift/549c86454382ecb3c400010c/app-root/runtime/repo/requirements.txt (line 11))
remote: Requirement already satisfied (use --upgrade to upgrade): six==1.8.0 in /var/lib/openshift/549c86454382ecb3c400010c/app-root/runtime/dependencies/python/virtenv/lib/python2.7/site-packages (from -r /var/lib/openshift/549c86454382ecb3c400010c/app-root/runtime/repo/requirements.txt (line 12))
remote: Requirement already satisfied (use --upgrade to upgrade): SQLAlchemy==0.9.8 in /var/lib/openshift/549c86454382ecb3c400010c/app-root/runtime/dependencies/python/virtenv/lib/python2.7/site-packages (from -r /var/lib/openshift/549c86454382ecb3c400010c/app-root/runtime/repo/requirements.txt (line 13))
remote: Requirement already satisfied (use --upgrade to upgrade): Werkzeug==0.9.6 in /var/lib/openshift/549c86454382ecb3c400010c/app-root/runtime/dependencies/python/virtenv/lib/python2.7/site-packages (from -r /var/lib/openshift/549c86454382ecb3c400010c/app-root/runtime/repo/requirements.txt (line 14))
remote: Requirement already satisfied (use --upgrade to upgrade): WTForms==2.0.1 in /var/lib/openshift/549c86454382ecb3c400010c/app-root/runtime/dependencies/python/virtenv/lib/python2.7/site-packages (from -r /var/lib/openshift/549c86454382ecb3c400010c/app-root/runtime/repo/requirements.txt (line 15))
remote: Installing collected packages: MySQL-python
remote:   Found existing installation: MySQL-python 1.2.3
remote:     Not uninstalling MySQL-python at /opt/rh/python27/root/usr/lib64/python2.7/site-packages, outside environment /var/lib/openshift/549c86454382ecb3c400010c/app-root/runtime/dependencies/python/virtenv
remote:   Running setup.py install for MySQL-python
remote:     building '_mysql' extension
remote:     gcc -pthread -fno-strict-aliasing -O2 -g -pipe -Wall -Wp,-D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -fexceptions -fstack-protector --param=ssp-buffer-size=4 -m64 -mtune=generic -D_GNU_SOURCE -fPIC -fwrapv -DNDEBUG -O2 -g -pipe -Wall -Wp,-D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -fexceptions -fstack-protector --param=ssp-buffer-size=4 -m64 -mtune=generic -D_GNU_SOURCE -fPIC -fwrapv -fPIC -Dversion_info=(1,2,5,'final',1) -D__version__=1.2.5 -I/opt/rh/mysql55/root/usr/include/mysql -I/opt/rh/python27/root/usr/include/python2.7 -c _mysql.c -o build/temp.linux-x86_64-2.7/_mysql.o -g -pipe -Wp,-D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -fexceptions -fstack-protector --param=ssp-buffer-size=4 -m64 -D_GNU_SOURCE -D_FILE_OFFSET_BITS=64 -D_LARGEFILE_SOURCE -fno-strict-aliasing -fwrapv -fPIC -fPIC -g -static-libgcc -fno-omit-frame-pointer -fno-strict-aliasing -DMY_PTHREAD_FASTMUTEX=1
remote:     In file included from /opt/rh/mysql55/root/usr/include/mysql/my_config.h:14,
remote:                      from _mysql.c:44:
remote:     /opt/rh/mysql55/root/usr/include/mysql/my_config_x86_64.h:422:1: warning: "HAVE_WCSCOLL" redefined
remote:     In file included from /opt/rh/python27/root/usr/include/python2.7/pyconfig.h:6,
remote:                      from /opt/rh/python27/root/usr/include/python2.7/Python.h:8,
remote:                      from _mysql.c:29:
remote:     /opt/rh/python27/root/usr/include/python2.7/pyconfig-64.h:908:1: warning: this is the location of the previous definition
remote:     gcc -pthread -shared -L/usr/lib6464 build/temp.linux-x86_64-2.7/_mysql.o -L/opt/rh/mysql55/root/usr/lib64/mysql -L/opt/rh/python27/root/usr/lib64 -lmysqlclient -lpthread -lz -lm -lrt -lssl -lcrypto -ldl -lpython2.7 -o build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/_mysql.so
remote:     /usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lmysqlclient
remote:     collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
remote:     error: command 'gcc' failed with exit status 1
remote:     Complete output from command /var/lib/openshift/549c86454382ecb3c400010c/python/virtenv/bin/python2.7 -c "import setuptools;__file__='/var/lib/openshift/549c86454382ecb3c400010c/app-root/runtime/dependencies/python/virtenv/build/MySQL-python/setup.py';exec(compile(open(__file__).read().replace('\r\n', '\n'), __file__, 'exec'))" install --record /tmp/pip-PDPMLU-record/install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --install-headers /var/lib/openshift/549c86454382ecb3c400010c/app-root/runtime/dependencies/python/virtenv/include/site/python2.7:
remote:     running install
remote: 
remote: running build
remote: 
remote: running build_py
remote: 
remote: creating build
remote: 
remote: creating build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7
remote: 
remote: copying _mysql_exceptions.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7
remote: 
remote: creating build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/MySQLdb
remote: 
remote: copying MySQLdb/__init__.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/MySQLdb
remote: 
remote: copying MySQLdb/converters.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/MySQLdb
remote: 
remote: copying MySQLdb/connections.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/MySQLdb
remote: 
remote: copying MySQLdb/cursors.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/MySQLdb
remote: 
remote: copying MySQLdb/release.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/MySQLdb
remote: 
remote: copying MySQLdb/times.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/MySQLdb
remote: 
remote: creating build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/MySQLdb/constants
remote: 
remote: copying MySQLdb/constants/__init__.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/MySQLdb/constants
remote: 
remote: copying MySQLdb/constants/CR.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/MySQLdb/constants
remote: 
remote: copying MySQLdb/constants/FIELD_TYPE.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/MySQLdb/constants
remote: 
remote: copying MySQLdb/constants/ER.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/MySQLdb/constants
remote: 
remote: copying MySQLdb/constants/FLAG.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/MySQLdb/constants
remote: 
remote: copying MySQLdb/constants/REFRESH.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/MySQLdb/constants
remote: 
remote: copying MySQLdb/constants/CLIENT.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/MySQLdb/constants
remote: 
remote: running build_ext
remote: 
remote: building '_mysql' extension
remote: 
remote: creating build/temp.linux-x86_64-2.7
remote: 
remote: gcc -pthread -fno-strict-aliasing -O2 -g -pipe -Wall -Wp,-D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -fexceptions -fstack-protector --param=ssp-buffer-size=4 -m64 -mtune=generic -D_GNU_SOURCE -fPIC -fwrapv -DNDEBUG -O2 -g -pipe -Wall -Wp,-D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -fexceptions -fstack-protector --param=ssp-buffer-size=4 -m64 -mtune=generic -D_GNU_SOURCE -fPIC -fwrapv -fPIC -Dversion_info=(1,2,5,'final',1) -D__version__=1.2.5 -I/opt/rh/mysql55/root/usr/include/mysql -I/opt/rh/python27/root/usr/include/python2.7 -c _mysql.c -o build/temp.linux-x86_64-2.7/_mysql.o -g -pipe -Wp,-D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -fexceptions -fstack-protector --param=ssp-buffer-size=4 -m64 -D_GNU_SOURCE -D_FILE_OFFSET_BITS=64 -D_LARGEFILE_SOURCE -fno-strict-aliasing -fwrapv -fPIC -fPIC -g -static-libgcc -fno-omit-frame-pointer -fno-strict-aliasing -DMY_PTHREAD_FASTMUTEX=1
remote: 
remote: In file included from /opt/rh/mysql55/root/usr/include/mysql/my_config.h:14,
remote: 
remote:                  from _mysql.c:44:
remote: 
remote: /opt/rh/mysql55/root/usr/include/mysql/my_config_x86_64.h:422:1: warning: "HAVE_WCSCOLL" redefined
remote: 
remote: In file included from /opt/rh/python27/root/usr/include/python2.7/pyconfig.h:6,
remote: 
remote:                  from /opt/rh/python27/root/usr/include/python2.7/Python.h:8,
remote: 
remote:                  from _mysql.c:29:
remote: 
remote: /opt/rh/python27/root/usr/include/python2.7/pyconfig-64.h:908:1: warning: this is the location of the previous definition
remote: 
remote: gcc -pthread -shared -L/usr/lib6464 build/temp.linux-x86_64-2.7/_mysql.o -L/opt/rh/mysql55/root/usr/lib64/mysql -L/opt/rh/python27/root/usr/lib64 -lmysqlclient -lpthread -lz -lm -lrt -lssl -lcrypto -ldl -lpython2.7 -o build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/_mysql.so
remote: 
remote: /usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lmysqlclient
remote: 
remote: collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
remote: 
remote: error: command 'gcc' failed with exit status 1
remote: 
remote: ----------------------------------------
remote:   Can't roll back MySQL-python; was not uninstalled
remote: Cleaning up...
remote: Command /var/lib/openshift/549c86454382ecb3c400010c/python/virtenv/bin/python2.7 -c "import setuptools;__file__='/var/lib/openshift/549c86454382ecb3c400010c/app-root/runtime/dependencies/python/virtenv/build/MySQL-python/setup.py';exec(compile(open(__file__).read().replace('\r\n', '\n'), __file__, 'exec'))" install --record /tmp/pip-PDPMLU-record/install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --install-headers /var/lib/openshift/549c86454382ecb3c400010c/app-root/runtime/dependencies/python/virtenv/include/site/python2.7 failed with error code 1 in /var/lib/openshift/549c86454382ecb3c400010c/app-root/runtime/dependencies/python/virtenv/build/MySQL-python
remote: Traceback (most recent call last):
remote:   File "/var/lib/openshift/549c86454382ecb3c400010c/python/virtenv/bin/pip", line 12, in <module>
remote:     load_entry_point('pip==1.4', 'console_scripts', 'pip')()
remote:   File "/var/lib/openshift/549c86454382ecb3c400010c/app-root/runtime/dependencies/python/virtenv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pip/__init__.py", line 147, in main
remote:     return command.main(args[1:], options)
remote:   File "/var/lib/openshift/549c86454382ecb3c400010c/app-root/runtime/dependencies/python/virtenv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pip/basecommand.py", line 171, in main
remote:     log_fp = open_logfile(log_fn, 'w')
remote:   File "/var/lib/openshift/549c86454382ecb3c400010c/app-root/runtime/dependencies/python/virtenv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pip/basecommand.py", line 200, in open_logfile
remote:     os.makedirs(dirname)
remote:   File "/var/lib/openshift/549c86454382ecb3c400010c/python/virtenv/lib64/python2.7/os.py", line 157, in makedirs
remote:     mkdir(name, mode)
remote: OSError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: '/var/lib/openshift/549c86454382ecb3c400010c/.pip'
remote: Running setup.py script..
remote: running develop
remote: running egg_info
remote: creating FlaskApp.egg-info
remote: writing requirements to FlaskApp.egg-info/requires.txt
remote: writing FlaskApp.egg-info/PKG-INFO
remote: writing top-level names to FlaskApp.egg-info/top_level.txt
remote: writing dependency_links to FlaskApp.egg-info/dependency_links.txt
remote: writing manifest file 'FlaskApp.egg-info/SOURCES.txt'
remote: reading manifest file 'FlaskApp.egg-info/SOURCES.txt'
remote: writing manifest file 'FlaskApp.egg-info/SOURCES.txt'
remote: running build_ext
remote: Creating /var/lib/openshift/549c86454382ecb3c400010c/app-root/runtime/dependencies/python/virtenv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/FlaskApp.egg-link (link to .)
remote: FlaskApp 1.0 is already the active version in easy-install.pth
remote: 
remote: Installed /var/lib/openshift/549c86454382ecb3c400010c/app-root/runtime/repo
remote: Processing dependencies for FlaskApp==1.0
remote: Searching for Flask==0.10.1
remote: Best match: Flask 0.10.1
remote: Processing Flask-0.10.1-py2.7.egg
remote: Flask 0.10.1 is already the active version in easy-install.pth
remote: 
remote: Using /var/lib/openshift/549c86454382ecb3c400010c/app-root/runtime/dependencies/python/virtenv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/Flask-0.10.1-py2.7.egg
remote: Searching for itsdangerous==0.24
remote: Best match: itsdangerous 0.24
remote: Processing itsdangerous-0.24-py2.7.egg
remote: itsdangerous 0.24 is already the active version in easy-install.pth
remote: 
remote: Using /var/lib/openshift/549c86454382ecb3c400010c/app-root/runtime/dependencies/python/virtenv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/itsdangerous-0.24-py2.7.egg
remote: Searching for Jinja2==2.7.3
remote: Best match: Jinja2 2.7.3
remote: Adding Jinja2 2.7.3 to easy-install.pth file
remote: 
remote: Using /var/lib/openshift/549c86454382ecb3c400010c/app-root/runtime/dependencies/python/virtenv/lib/python2.7/site-packages
remote: Searching for Werkzeug==0.9.6
remote: Best match: Werkzeug 0.9.6
remote: Adding Werkzeug 0.9.6 to easy-install.pth file
remote: 
remote: Using /var/lib/openshift/549c86454382ecb3c400010c/app-root/runtime/dependencies/python/virtenv/lib/python2.7/site-packages
remote: Searching for MarkupSafe==0.23
remote: Best match: MarkupSafe 0.23
remote: Adding MarkupSafe 0.23 to easy-install.pth file
remote: 
remote: Using /var/lib/openshift/549c86454382ecb3c400010c/app-root/runtime/dependencies/python/virtenv/lib/python2.7/site-packages
remote: Finished processing dependencies for FlaskApp==1.0
remote: Script /var/lib/openshift/549c86454382ecb3c400010c/python//virtenv/bin/activate.fish cannot be made relative (it's not a normal script that starts with #!/var/lib/openshift/549c86454382ecb3c400010c/python/virtenv/bin/python)
remote: Script /var/lib/openshift/549c86454382ecb3c400010c/python//virtenv/bin/activate.csh cannot be made relative (it's not a normal script that starts with #!/var/lib/openshift/549c86454382ecb3c400010c/python/virtenv/bin/python)
remote: Preparing build for deployment
remote: Deployment id is 0aeb5dd6
remote: Activating deployment
remote: HAProxy already running
remote: HAProxy instance is started
remote: Script /var/lib/openshift/549c86454382ecb3c400010c/python//virtenv/bin/activate.fish cannot be made relative (it's not a normal script that starts with #!/var/lib/openshift/549c86454382ecb3c400010c/python/virtenv/bin/python)
remote: Script /var/lib/openshift/549c86454382ecb3c400010c/python//virtenv/bin/activate.csh cannot be made relative (it's not a normal script that starts with #!/var/lib/openshift/549c86454382ecb3c400010c/python/virtenv/bin/python)
remote: Starting Python 2.7 cartridge (app.py server)
remote: -------------------------
remote: Git Post-Receive Result: success
remote: Activation status: success
remote: Deployment completed with status: success
```

And this is the rhc tail command:

```
==> app-root/logs/python.log-20141226024118 <==
  File "/opt/rh/python27/root/usr/lib64/python2.7/socket.py", line 303, in flush
    self._sock.sendall(view[write_offset:write_offset+buffer_size])
error: [Errno 32] Broken pipe
----------------------------------------
127.13.64.129 - - [26/Dec/2014 02:41:18] "GET / HTTP/1.0" 200 -
----------------------------------------
Exception happened during processing of request from ('127.13.64.129', 20268)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/opt/rh/python27/root/usr/lib64/python2.7/SocketServer.py", line 295, in _handle_request_noblock
    self.process_request(request, client_address)

==> app-root/logs/python.log-20141226073626 <==
127.13.64.129 - - [26/Dec/2014 07:36:26] "GET / HTTP/1.0" 200 -
----------------------------------------
Exception happened during processing of request from ('127.13.64.129', 29632)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/opt/rh/python27/root/usr/lib64/python2.7/SocketServer.py", line 295, in _handle_request_noblock
    self.process_request(request, client_address)
  File "/opt/rh/python27/root/usr/lib64/python2.7/SocketServer.py", line 321, in process_request
    self.finish_request(request, client_address)
  File "/opt/rh/python27/root/usr/lib64/python2.7/SocketServer.py", line 334, in finish_request
    self.RequestHandlerClass(request, client_address, self)

==> app-root/logs/python.log-20141225094557 <==
    self._sock.sendall(view[write_offset:write_offset+buffer_size])
error: [Errno 32] Broken pipe
----------------------------------------
127.13.64.129 - - [25/Dec/2014 21:45:57] "GET / HTTP/1.0" 200 -
----------------------------------------
Exception happened during processing of request from ('127.13.64.129', 22441)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/opt/rh/python27/root/usr/lib64/python2.7/SocketServer.py", line 295, in _handle_request_noblock
    self.process_request(request, client_address)
  File "/opt/rh/python27/root/usr/lib64/python2.7/SocketServer.py", line 321, in process_request

==> app-root/logs/haproxy.log <==
[WARNING] 359/153915 (493821) : Server express/local-gear is UP (leaving maintenance).
[WARNING] 359/154912 (46051) : config : log format ignored for proxy 'stats' since it has no log address.
[WARNING] 359/154912 (46051) : config : log format ignored for proxy 'express' since it has no log address.
[WARNING] 359/154912 (493821) : Stopping proxy stats in 0 ms.
[WARNING] 359/154912 (493821) : Stopping proxy express in 0 ms.
[WARNING] 359/154912 (493821) : Proxy stats stopped (FE: 4 conns, BE: 0 conns).
[WARNING] 359/154912 (493821) : Proxy express stopped (FE: 28 conns, BE: 28 conns).
[WARNING] 359/155417 (46051) : Server express/local-gear is DOWN for maintenance.
[ALERT] 359/155417 (46051) : proxy 'express' has no server available!
[WARNING] 359/155445 (46051) : Server express/local-gear is UP (leaving maintenance).

==> app-root/logs/haproxy_ctld.log <==
I, [2014-12-25T16:52:03.544221 #363070]  INFO -- : Starting haproxy_ctld
I, [2014-12-26T14:54:21.950056 #454284]  INFO -- : Starting haproxy_ctld
I, [2014-12-26T15:05:45.382845 #476536]  INFO -- : Starting haproxy_ctld
I, [2014-12-26T15:12:54.659244 #493843]  INFO -- : Starting haproxy_ctld

==> app-root/logs/python.log-20141226123259 <==
Exception happened during processing of request from ('127.13.64.129', 22475)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/opt/rh/python27/root/usr/lib64/python2.7/SocketServer.py", line 295, in _handle_request_noblock
    self.process_request(request, client_address)
  File "/opt/rh/python27/root/usr/lib64/python2.7/SocketServer.py", line 321, in process_request
    self.finish_request(request, client_address)
  File "/opt/rh/python27/root/usr/lib64/python2.7/SocketServer.py", line 334, in finish_request
    self.RequestHandlerClass(request, client_address, self)
  File "/opt/rh/python27/root/usr/lib64/python2.7/SocketServer.py", line 651, in __init__
    self.finish()

==> app-root/logs/python.log <==
  File "/opt/rh/python27/root/usr/lib64/python2.7/SocketServer.py", line 651, in __init__
    self.finish()
  File "/opt/rh/python27/root/usr/lib64/python2.7/SocketServer.py", line 710, in finish
    self.wfile.close()
  File "/opt/rh/python27/root/usr/lib64/python2.7/socket.py", line 279, in close
    self.flush()
  File "/opt/rh/python27/root/usr/lib64/python2.7/socket.py", line 303, in flush
    self._sock.sendall(view[write_offset:write_offset+buffer_size])
error: [Errno 32] Broken pipe
----------------------------------------
127.13.64.129 - - [26/Dec/2014 16:02:20] "GET / HTTP/1.0" 200 -
----------------------------------------
Exception happened during processing of request from ('127.13.64.129', 22815)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/opt/rh/python27/root/usr/lib64/python2.7/SocketServer.py", line 295, in _handle_request_noblock
    self.process_request(request, client_address)
  File "/opt/rh/python27/root/usr/lib64/python2.7/SocketServer.py", line 321, in process_request
    self.finish_request(request, client_address)
  File "/opt/rh/python27/root/usr/lib64/python2.7/SocketServer.py", line 334, in finish_request
    self.RequestHandlerClass(request, client_address, self)
  File "/opt/rh/python27/root/usr/lib64/python2.7/SocketServer.py", line 651, in __init__
    self.finish()
  File "/opt/rh/python27/root/usr/lib64/python2.7/SocketServer.py", line 710, in finish
    self.wfile.close()
  File "/opt/rh/python27/root/usr/lib64/python2.7/socket.py", line 279, in close
    self.flush()
  File "/opt/rh/python27/root/usr/lib64/python2.7/socket.py", line 303, in flush
    self._sock.sendall(view[write_offset:write_offset+buffer_size])
error: [Errno 32] Broken pipe
----------------------------------------
127.13.64.129 - - [26/Dec/2014 16:02:22] "GET / HTTP/1.0" 200 -
----------------------------------------
Exception happened during processing of request from ('127.13.64.129', 22818)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/opt/rh/python27/root/usr/lib64/python2.7/SocketServer.py", line 295, in _handle_request_noblock
    self.process_request(request, client_address)
  File "/opt/rh/python27/root/usr/lib64/python2.7/SocketServer.py", line 321, in process_request
    self.finish_request(request, client_address)
  File "/opt/rh/python27/root/usr/lib64/python2.7/SocketServer.py", line 334, in finish_request
    self.RequestHandlerClass(request, client_address, self)
  File "/opt/rh/python27/root/usr/lib64/python2.7/SocketServer.py", line 651, in __init__
    self.finish()
  File "/opt/rh/python27/root/usr/lib64/python2.7/SocketServer.py", line 710, in finish
    self.wfile.close()
  File "/opt/rh/python27/root/usr/lib64/python2.7/socket.py", line 279, in close
    self.flush()
  File "/opt/rh/python27/root/usr/lib64/python2.7/socket.py", line 303, in flush
    self._sock.sendall(view[write_offset:write_offset+buffer_size])
error: [Errno 32] Broken pipe
----------------------------------------
127.13.64.129 - - [26/Dec/2014 16:02:24] "GET / HTTP/1.0" 200 -
----------------------------------------
Exception happened during processing of request from ('127.13.64.129', 22829)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/opt/rh/python27/root/usr/lib64/python2.7/SocketServer.py", line 295, in _handle_request_noblock
    self.process_request(request, client_address)
  File "/opt/rh/python27/root/usr/lib64/python2.7/SocketServer.py", line 321, in process_request
    self.finish_request(request, client_address)
  File "/opt/rh/python27/root/usr/lib64/python2.7/SocketServer.py", line 334, in finish_request
    self.RequestHandlerClass(request, client_address, self)
  File "/opt/rh/python27/root/usr/lib64/python2.7/SocketServer.py", line 651, in __init__
    self.finish()
  File "/opt/rh/python27/root/usr/lib64/python2.7/SocketServer.py", line 710, in finish
    self.wfile.close()
  File "/opt/rh/python27/root/usr/lib64/python2.7/socket.py", line 279, in close
    self.flush()
  File "/opt/rh/python27/root/usr/lib64/python2.7/socket.py", line 303, in flush
    self._sock.sendall(view[write_offset:write_offset+buffer_size])
error: [Errno 32] Broken pipe

----------------------------------------
```

Comment: Does your OpenShift account have mysql enabled?

Comment: Yes it is enable. Plus i have added new tables.

Answer (score 0):

Based on the output you provided, OpenShift likely installed the MySQL core package but didn't install the MySQL development package, which includes the library files your Python package needs.

Try installing the `mysql-devel` package from `yum` in your OpenShift environment<sup>1</sup>:

```
$ yum install --assumeyes mysql-devel
```

Then reinstall your Python packages (or redeploy, if it does this for you).

If you have success with installing this package (and compiling your Python extension), consider adding this prerequisite to your application's [OpenShift Action Hooks](https://developers.openshift.com/en/managing-action-hooks.html).

<sup>1</sup> `--assumeyes` is optional; it suppresses questions.

Comment: I've tried but without success, i have new error message: cannot open Packages database in /var/lib/rpm
CRITICAL:yum.main:

Error: rpmdb open failed

Comment: @Ricardo This is an unrelated issue but the general consensus seems to be to rebuild your rpm database indices: `$ rm -f /var/lib/rpm/__* && rpm --rebuilddb`. If this is an new instance, you should contact RedHat support. `yum` is a core package that should "just work" in a default installation.

Comment: thanks for your help, but I actually give up and now I will try to make an simply application(flask+mysql only) with less business logic.

Answer (score -1):

After trying a several ways to make things work I found a way to achieve it.
Just delete the line `MySQL-python==1.2.5` from your pip requirements file.

My working code can be found in https://github.com/rchampa/openshift-template-python-flask-mysql